# scroll to next div by js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know there are lots of same examples, but their code don't work. Please Help! So I have arrow Image at the bottom of container block. The content of container are flex( if it is important to know?!) And when i click on arrow, it should move down by next container.

```js
$("#arrow").click(function() {
  var $target = $('.container.active').next('.container');
  if ($target.length == 0)
    $target = $('.container:first');

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $target.offset().top
  }, 'slow');

  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $target.addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container first active" id="first">
  ///not important content
  <button class="next">
            <img src="arrow.png" id="arrow" alt="down">click
        </button>
</div>
<div class="container second" id="second">
  <div class="arrow">
    <img src="arrowup.png" alt="up">
  </div>
  <div class="arrow">
    <img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/w7duthsa/ Try this. U should be careful where arrow event fires. It is in icon. u have to click to icon to run. Button doesn't down.

```
$("#arrow").on("click", function(e) {
    $(document).scrollTop($(this).parent().parent().next().offset().top);
    return false; // prevent anchor
});
```

If u want to give up down to button then give arrow id to button and use function below https://jsfiddle.net/w7duthsa/1/

```
 $("#arrow").on("click", function(e) {
        $(document).scrollTop($(this).parent().next().offset().top);
        return false; // prevent anchor
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use anchor tag and pass id of div you want to focus. Below is an example for that.

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.second, .first{
border : 1px solid black;
height : 500px;
width:100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container first active" id="first">
  <!-- not important content -->
  <a href="#second">
          <img src="arrow.png" id="arrow" alt="down">click
    </a>
</div>
<div class="container second" id="second">
  <a class="arrow" href="#first">
    <img src="arrowup.png" alt="up">
  </a>
  <div class="arrow">
    <img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow">
  </div>
</div>
```